# A Problem regarding properties of a matrix and the dimention of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $A^2+B^2=AB$ and $AB-BA$ is invertible . Show that $3$ divides $n.$

Comment: The question looks interesting, but is completely missing context. How did you come across this question? What makes you think this might be true?

Comment: Presumably the matrices are real. Then this is problem 3 of the 1997 IMC Day 1. A solution can be found at [http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1997/prob_sol1.pdf](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1997/prob_sol1.pdf). By the way, I voted to close this question due to lack of context.